# Vue class binding on this input field

Tags: vuejs2

I would like to bind a class on the input field where this class is suppose to be applied. In my case I have input fields that I am dynamically creating and since I can't bind values with v-model for input fields that are dynamically created I can't bind the class with `v-model` data.
This are the fields that I am creating inside of `v-for` loop:

```
  <template v-for="input in ninjaForm.fields">
    <div class="control">
      <input
        class="input is-large"
        :class="{ hasValue: input.value }"
        :ref="input.label.toLowerCase()"
        :type="input.type"
        :name="input.label.toLowerCase()"
        :required="input.required == 1">
      <label>{{ input.label }}</label>
    </div>
  </template>
```

I would like to know how can I bind a class now with that input field, so that I can check if the input field has some kind of value, so for example something like this:

```
:class="{ 'has-value' : this.input.value != ''}"
```

Hoe can I do that with Vue?

Comment: what is `hasValue` is it a css class or a data?

Comment: It is a css class

Comment: Do you want something like this? https://jsfiddle.net/943bx5px/12/ if you enter color "red" or "green" you can see the input value bind to the class

Comment: But, like I stated in the question, I get an error when I bind class with v-model, since I am creating fields dynamically.

Comment: what fields are you creating dynamically? Please clarify your question. I don't even see your v-model in the example

Comment: This input field is being created inside the v-for loop, you are not seeing v-model, because I am not using v-model, because like I said I get an error when I use v-model, since vue throws an error for dynamically creating fields with v-model

Comment: Could you please provide us a JSFiddle sample where we can easily reproduce your issue ?

Answer (score 1):

I think that you're trying to do a [class binding using the Object Syntax](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html#Object-Syntax)

In your example, to apply the CSS class `hasValue` if your input has any value that isn't falsy, you'll have something like this :

```
<input
  class="input is-large"
  :class="{ hasValue: input.value }"
  :ref="input.label.toLowerCase()"
  :type="input.type"
  :name="input.label.toLowerCase()"
  :required="input.required == 1">
<label>{{ input.label }}</label>
```

Comment: Yes, my syntax was wrong but even with your correct syntax, I am not able to bind the class to any data value like the values from v-model, so that is what I am looking for, some way to bind a value with that specific input and not with some value from the component data object.